# css3 transitions for more than one element on a page and how to reverse transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I'm doing a Jquery Mobile site with two panels which I want to CSS-pop instead of using plain `show()`/`hide()`.

I started with this:

Show:

```
 if ( $popPanel.attr('status') == 'hidden' ) {
      $popPanel.attr('status','visible')    
          .addClass('ui-panel-active pop in')
          .show('fast')
          .removeClass('in')                
          ...
```

Hide:

```
 $(this).attr('status', 'hidden')   
   .addClass('reverse out') 
   .hide('fast')
   .removeClass('ui-panel-active reverse out pop')
   ...
```

which did not work, because I believe I'm removing the transition classes before the actual transition takes place. But even when I change it to:

```
 if ( $popPanel.attr('status') == 'hidden' ) {
      $popPanel.attr('status','visible')    
          .addClass('ui-panel-active pop in')
          .show('fast')
          ...
          window.setTimeout( function() {
             console.log("fired"+$popPanel.jqmData('id') );
             $popPanel.removeClass('in');
             }, 350);
```

I can only get the transition to show on the first popup. The other popup just shows up (with 350 delay), although it is correctly identified in the console.

#### Questions

- Can I use CSS3 transitions on more than one element on page? Any hints what I'm doing wrong
- The pop out transition does not show at all, even with setTimeout. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it too complicated. [Here is a simple example of what I think are trying to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/4TxqZ/) Essentially, you can do away with all those transition classes. You really only need an "on" class ("active", in my example). CSS will take care of the rest.